# can I use if and for statement iside map method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the following code with map or filter methods 
is it possible to do that:

```
function doubleOddNumbers(numbers) {
  const newNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      newNumbers.push(numbers[i] * 2);
    }
  }
  return newNumbers;
}

const myNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(doubleOddNumbers(myNumbers);

// Do not change or remove anything below this line
module.exports = {
  myNumbers,
  doubleOddNumbers,
};
```

Comment: This would work for filtering.Not for map though

Comment: why not? `map` and `filter` take function inside

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with map()>?

Answer (score 1):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the odd numbers and return the doubled value using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function doubleOddNumbers(numbers) {
  return numbers.filter(n => n % 2).map(n => n * 2)
}

/* This would also work
function doubleOddNumbers(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((r, n) => n % 2 ? r.concat(n * 2) : r, [])
}
*/
const myNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(doubleOddNumbers(myNumbers));
```

Comment: can explain the reduce part please.

Answer (score -1):

Use reduce

```
function doubleOddNumbers(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((allNumbers, number) => {
    if (number % 2 === 1) {
      allNumbers.push(number * 2);
    }
    return allNumbers;
  }, []);
}
```